# SQL: How to only look up unique values

Tags: sql, sas

I have a piece of code that does what I need. But it looks complicated and messy for what it does. Is there a simpler way to look up the member CIN unqiuely without having a create a sub-query?

1. Get the unique items from DATA (often it has hundreds of duplicate ID), but each ID has their own service date. Sometimes a ID has 20-30 service date in the input.
2. Lookup their member ID from a different table
3. Sometimes there are 2-3 member ID for each Personal ID
4. Join it back together with original

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide 6.1, thanks!

```
/* Look up the member ID using Personal ID*/
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.MemberID AS 
SELECT c.PersonalID, 
    c.SBSID,
    c.SITEID,
    d.DateOfService FORMAT=MMDDYY10.,
    INTNX('month', d.DateOfService, 0, 'END') AS EndOfMonth FORMAT=MMDDYY10.,
    d.RateCode, 
    d.TCN,
    d.ClaimAmount FORMAT=DOLLAR10.2
/* Get every Membmer ID associated with the Personal Number*/
FROM SASUSER.DATA d
    RIGHT JOIN (
    /*****************************************************/
    /* Subquery 2: to Match the PersonalID with MemberID */
        SELECT PersonalID, 
            MEMBERID AS SBSID,
            SITEID
        FROM DW_SOME_TABLE b INNER JOIN ( 
        /****************************************************/
        /* Subquery 1: Select only the distinct Personal ID */
            SELECT DISTINCT PersonalID 
            FROM SASUSER.DATA 
            WHERE PersonalID is not null
        ) a 
        /* End of Subquery 1*/ 
        /****************************************************/
        ON (a.PersonalID = b.CINNUMBER)
        WHERE (b.SITEID = '0001')
    ) c ON (c.PersonalID = d.PersonalID)
    /* End of Subquery 2*/
    /*****************************************************/
ORDER BY c.PersonalID;
QUIT;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually need *Subquery 1*, from which table is the `MEMBERID` in *Subquery 2*? Btw, you're not using *subqueries* (those are Selects within the WHERE-clause, usually using IN), but *Derived Tables* (sometimes called *Sub-Select*)

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your tables and indexes, without which it's hard to give a good review.  I recommend you include these definitions (preferably as SQL statements, so that reviewers can reproduce your test environment).

Answer (score 1):

We are JOINing tables A, B, C, D here, mostly on a personal ID.
The structure is more nested than necessary.
I suspect it was built up iteratively by adding onto existing queries.

Recommend that we just turn this into a simple 4-table JOIN,
putting them all at the same level.

## distinct

```
            SELECT DISTINCT PersonalID 
            FROM SASUSER.DATA ...
```

This seems to be where the trouble starts.
Alas, we don't already have some table that conveniently has PersonalID as
[PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key#Design).

Rather than a DISTINCT, recommend you accomplish the same thing
with a GROUP BY PersonalID.
That lets you elevate it to same level as the other tables.